# Android app permissions as shown to user

Tags: android, android-permissions

what does the permission "*broadcast data messages to apps*" mean?
On the Play-store I can see this app permission but I cannot figure out which permission in the code does this map to exactly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Sonal

Comment: Based on a Google search on your quoted expression: http://androidpermissions.com/permission/com.google.android.permission.BROADCAST_DATA_MESSAGE

Answer (score 3):

The messages you posted is for following permission

```
com.google.android.permission.BROADCAST_DATA_MESSAGE
```

Description of the permission:

> Can broadcast data messages received from the Internet to apps
>   registered to listen for them.